# Adding actions to DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: file, action, jtree, double-click, treenode

I have created a "FileTree" class which displays a file system via a JTree, and only displays folders and ".xlsx" or ".xls" files. I want to be able to add a double-click action to the DefaultMutableTreeNodes if they are a ".xlsx" or ".xls" file. It doesnt seem possible to be able to add an ActionListener or a MouseListener to a DefaultMutableTreeNode, is there a way I can control the double-click action on these nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution of sorts, its not the one I was looking for, but it does work.

I have added a MouseListener to the JTree, and then when the click count is 2, I check the event source is an instanceof the JTree, then call

```
Object comp = tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
if (comp instanceof FileTreeNode)
{
    FileTreeNode ftn = (FileTreeNode) comp;
File file = ftn.getFile();
}
```

and then I can do whatever I want with the file. FileTreeNode is an extension of DefaultMutableTreeNode which contains the file at that node.